# Linux mdadm + LVM2: "Cloned" logical volume across three RAID1 blocks?

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, mdadm, raid1

My disk setup in a Debian Linux box shows like this:

```
> lsblk

NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1              8:1    0   384M  0 part  
├─sda2              8:2    0    48G  0 part  
│ └─md3             9:3    0    48G  0 raid1 
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
├─sda3              8:3    0    48G  0 part  
│ └─md4             9:4    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
├─sda4              8:4    0   835G  0 part
│ └─md5             9:5    0 834,8G  0 raid1
│   ├─vg1-lvroot  253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
│   ├─vg1-lvhome  253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /home
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
└─sda5              8:5    0     1M  0 part
sdc                 8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdc1              8:33   0   384M  0 part
├─sdc2              8:34   0    48G  0 part
│ └─md3             9:3    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
├─sdc3              8:35   0    48G  0 part
│ └─md4             9:4    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
├─sdc4              8:36   0   835G  0 part
│ └─md5             9:5    0 834,8G  0 raid1
│   ├─vg1-lvroot  253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
│   ├─vg1-lvhome  253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /home
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
└─sdc5              8:37   0     1M  0 part
```

However I installed each of the logical volumes on a different RAID1 segment so I expected the output to be like this:

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1              8:1    0   384M  0 part  
├─sda2              8:2    0    48G  0 part  
│ └─md3             9:3    0    48G  0 raid1 
│   └─vg1-lvroot  253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
├─sda3              8:3    0    48G  0 part  
│ └─md4             9:4    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvhome  253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /home
├─sda4              8:4    0   835G  0 part
│ └─md5             9:5    0 834,8G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
└─sda5              8:5    0     1M  0 part
sdc                 8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdc1              8:33   0   384M  0 part
├─sdc2              8:34   0    48G  0 part
│ └─md3             9:3    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvroot  253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
├─sdc3              8:35   0    48G  0 part
│ └─md4             9:4    0    48G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvhome  253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /home
├─sdc4              8:36   0   835G  0 part
│ └─md5             9:5    0 834,8G  0 raid1
│   └─vg1-lvdata 253:2    0 830,8G  0 lvm   /usr/local/share/data
└─sdc5              8:37   0     1M  0 part
```

So why is `lvdata` showing three times on three different RAID1 segments and why are `lvroot` and `lvdata` living together on the same and unintended segment?

Comment: lsblk output is usually correct. Most likely, LVM did not allocate the LVs the way you expected it to. Check with LVM which physical segments it uses for each LV.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to achieve. If you’re willing to use LVM, why not create a single RAID 1 array, with a single physical volume, a single volume group and 3 logical volumes? Otherwise, you might choose not to use LVM, and build your 3 filesystems directly on top of your 3 RAID 1 arrays.

Comment: Yes but for the time I made the setup I thought that setting a single RAID 1 array on a whole disk instead of three would impact disk throughput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following frostshutz' advice (thank you!) I realized that I had set one single volume group to shelter all three RAID1 physical volumes. I should have created one volume group per RAID1 segment instead. My fault then.